# ¿Es posible modificar el atributo de una etiqueta html con un dato de un archivo json? Si es así, cómo? sino, ¿qué debería hacer?

Tags: html, angular, json

En mi archivo HTML tengo una animación para los svg que va pintando el svg de izquierda a derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<svg id="svg_circle" viewBox = '0 0 24 24'> <!--rellenar viewBox-->
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="fill-horizontally">
                        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#423549">
                            <animate dur="3s" attributeName="offset"  
                            fill="freeze" from="0" to="0.3" repeatCount="indefinite"/>   
                        </stop>
                        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#3b2e42"></stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <path 
                    class="path"  
                    fill="url(#fill-horizontally)" 
                    stroke-width="1" 
                    opacity="1"
                    d="M9.931 12.645h4.138l-2.07-4.908m0-7.737L.68 3.982l1.726 14.771L12 24l9.596-5.242L23.32 3.984 11.999.001zm7.064 18.31h-2.638l-1.422-3.503H8.996l-1.422 3.504h-2.64L12 2.65z"
                    id="svg_1"
                /> <!--rellenar d-->
            </svg>
```

Busco que me manden los atributos "d" y "viewBox" en un formulario para rellenar esos atributos con datos personalizados. Por ahora utilizo un archivo .json para modificarlos. Pido esos datos porque descubrí que le dan al svg el tamaño y el dibujo correctos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**ARCHIVO JSON:**

```
"hard-skills":
    [
        {
            "id":6,
            "name": "Angular",
            "level": "básico",
            "viewBox": "0 0 24 24",
            "d": "M9.931 12.645h4.138l-2.07-4.908m0-7.737L.68 3.982l1.726 14.771L12 24l9.596-5.242L23.32 3.984 11.999.001zm7.064 18.31h-2.638l-1.422-3.503H8.996l-1.422 3.504h-2.64L12 2.65z"
        },
        {
            "id":7,
            "name": "Bootstrap",
            "level": "intermedio",
            "viewBox": "0 0 24 24",
            "d": "M4.98488 2C3.61546 2 2.60217 3.19858 2.64753 4.49844C2.69105 5.74725 2.63451 7.36461 2.22732 8.68359C1.81892 10.0064 1.1282 10.8444 0 10.952V12.1666C1.1282 12.2742 1.81892 13.1122 2.22732 14.4351C2.63451 15.754 2.69105 17.3714 2.64753 18.6202C2.60217 19.9199 3.61546 21.1186 4.98508 21.1186H19.0169C20.3864 21.1186 21.3995 19.9201 21.3541 18.6202C21.3106 17.3714 21.3671 15.754 21.7743 14.4351C22.1829 13.1122 22.8718 12.2742 24 12.1666V10.952C22.8718 10.8444 22.1829 10.0064 21.7743 8.68359C21.3671 7.36481 21.3106 5.74725 21.3541 4.49844C21.3995 3.19878 20.3864 2 19.0169 2H4.98468H4.98488ZM16.2712 13.7687C16.2712 15.5586 14.9361 16.6441 12.7206 16.6441H8.94915C8.84127 16.6441 8.7378 16.6012 8.66152 16.5249C8.58523 16.4486 8.54237 16.3452 8.54237 16.2373V6.88136C8.54237 6.77347 8.58523 6.67001 8.66152 6.59372C8.7378 6.51743 8.84127 6.47458 8.94915 6.47458H12.6991C14.5464 6.47458 15.7588 7.47525 15.7588 9.01166C15.7588 10.09 14.9433 11.0555 13.9041 11.2245V11.2809C15.3187 11.4361 16.2712 12.4156 16.2712 13.7687ZM12.3094 7.76407H10.1589V10.8015H11.9701C13.3702 10.8015 14.1423 10.2377 14.1423 9.2299C14.1423 8.28556 13.4784 7.76407 12.3094 7.76407ZM10.1589 12.0068V15.3542H12.3885C13.8462 15.3542 14.6184 14.7692 14.6184 13.6699C14.6184 12.5704 13.8246 12.0066 12.2947 12.0066H10.1589V12.0068Z"
        },
        {
            "id":5,
            "name": "HTML5",
            "level": "avanzado",
            "viewBox": "0 0 32 32",
            "d": "M11.677 13.196l-0.289-3.387 12.536 0.004 0.287-3.268-16.421-0.004 0.87 9.983h11.374l-0.406 4.27-3.627 1.002-3.683-1.009-0.234-2.63h-3.252l0.411 5.198 6.757 1.807 6.704-1.798 0.927-10.166h-11.954zM2.914 1.045h26.172l-2.38 26.874-10.734 3.037-10.673-3.038z"
        }
    ]
```

Entonces intento rellenar con esos valores a los atributos pero me saltan errores.
Un intento fallido para que se den idea de lo que quiero hacer:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
DATOS EXTRAS POR LAS DUDAS:
**HTML:**

```
<article>
    <div class="title-add-hard">
        <h3>HARD SKILLS</h3> <app-hard-skills-add-modal></app-hard-skills-add-modal> <!--arreglar posicion-->
    </div> 
    <div class="hard-skills">

        <div class="hard-skill" *ngFor="let hard of hardSkills">
            <div class="buttons">
                <app-hard-skill-edit-modal></app-hard-skill-edit-modal>
                <app-delete-modal></app-delete-modal> <!--arreglar posicion-->
            </div>
            <svg id="svg_circle" viewBox = '0 0 24 24'> <!--rellenar dato-->
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="fill-horizontally">
                        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#423549">
                            <animate dur="3s" attributeName="offset"  
                            fill="freeze" from="0" to="0.3" repeatCount="indefinite"/>   
                        </stop>
                        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#3b2e42"></stop>
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <path 
                    class="path"  
                    fill="url(#fill-horizontally)" 
                    stroke-width="1" 
                    opacity="1"
                    d="M9.931 12.645h4.138l-2.07-4.908m0-7.737L.68 3.982l1.726 14.771L12 24l9.596-5.242L23.32 3.984 11.999.001zm7.064 18.31h-2.638l-1.422-3.503H8.996l-1.422 3.504h-2.64L12 2.65z"
                    id="svg_1"
                />
            </svg> <!--rellenar dato-->
            <h4>{{hard.name}}</h4> <!--rellenar dato-->
            <p>{{hard.level}}</p> <!--rellenar dato-->
        </div>
        
    </div>
</article>
```

TYPESCRIPT (Servicios)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { usersService } from 'src/app/service/users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hard-skills',
  templateUrl: './hard-skills.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hard-skills.component.css']
})
export class HardSkillsComponent implements OnInit {
  hardSkills:any;
  constructor(private hardData: usersService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hardData.getData().subscribe(data =>{
      this.hardSkills = data.hardSkills;
    })
  }

}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class usersService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('./assets/data/data.json')
  }
}
```

Usé Angular y Bootstrap.